# Unity3D - Multiple enemies patrolling multiple paths in the same script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new writing code. The enemy will patrol between two paths. Then when the player enters the detection area around the enemy it will follow the player.

If I wanted more than 1 enemy and multiple paths, how would I add to this code to be able to do that. Creating a script for each enemy would be a waste, correct?

```
public var enemyPath1 : Transform;
public var enemyPath2 : Transform;
private var target : Transform = null;
private var characterControls: CharacterController;

function Start ()
{
    SetTarget(enemyPath1);
    characterControls = GetComponent(CharacterController);
}

function SetTarget(newTarget : Transform) : void
{
    target = newTarget;
}

function Update() : void
{
    var lookAtPosition : Vector3 = Vector3(target.position.x,
                                           this.transform.position.y,
                                           target.position.z);
    transform.LookAt(lookAtPosition);
    characterControls.SimpleMove(transform.forward);
}

function OnTriggerEnter(node : Collider) : void
{
    if(node.transform == target)
    {
        if(target == enemyPath1)
        {
            SetTarget(enemyPath2);
        }
        else if(target == enemyPath2)
        {
            SetTarget(enemyPath1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is supposed to go inside the enemy gameobject, right?
One way of doing is to put all the desired paths inside an array, in the order they are supposed to be followed by the enemy.

```
    var paths : Transform[];
    var pathIndex : int = 0;
    // Then in your start function:
    function Start ()
    {
        SetTarget(paths[pathIndex]);
        characterControls = GetComponent(CharacterController);
    }
    // Then in the function that is doing the checking and looking for the next path
    function OnTriggerEnter(node : Collider) : void
    {
        if(node.transform == target)
        {
            // Increment the index so it looks for the next path object
            pathIndex += 1;
            if(pathIndex == paths.length)
            {
                // Resets to the first path if this is the last one
                pathIndex = 0;
            }
            SetTarget(paths[pathIndex]);
        }
    }
```

So you can just add this script to all the enemy gameobjects in your scene, then in the editor you can manually set their paths variable to whatever paths you wish in the desired order, and they should follow their set routine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this by waypoint. Suppose there are 3 waypoint then enemy will first go to first then second then third then first ..... Thus cycle repeat. In the next code you can use raycasting to detect player

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] wayPoints;
[SerializeField] private float speed = 2f;
private int currentWayPointIndex = 0;

private void Update()
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(wayPoints[currentWayPointIndex].transform.position, transform.position) < 0.2f)
    {
        currentWayPointIndex++;
        if (currentWayPointIndex >= wayPoints.Length)
        {
            currentWayPointIndex = 0;
        }
        FlipTransform();
    }

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, wayPoints[currentWayPointIndex].transform.position,
        Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```